# What could be causing a delay in TCP ACK in my app

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a .NET windows service that uses an open source library (Asterisk.net - C#) to listen to TCP connections on a specific port.

This service is deployed on a number of VM instances of Windows 7 (all from the same source image).  The connections all come from the VM host (centos).  On one (and only one) of these instances the ACK response from windows to the connecting client is delayed by three seconds on the occasional incoming connection.  Other times, the ACK is sent immediately.

This delay causes the client to time out:

[image: Wireshark trace]

I'm no expert at TCP sockets, but it seems from a debug that these ACKs are sent before the connection is handed to the app (or in this case library), and even if the accepting thread is blocked, so it is a problem at the windows or .net library level?

The code that handles the inbound connections quickly hands it off to a thread and returns.

```
    public IO.SocketConnection Accept()
    {
        if (tcpListener != null)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (tcpClient != null)
                return new IO.SocketConnection(tcpClient, encoding);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So, what could be causing this infuriating delay?  What am I missing?

Comment: It's not your code. It's something external.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected this.  Now to work out what that external issue is.

Comment: If you have multiple VM, what is the difference between them? Different applications, different background services running, ...? Try with a new image instead of the faulty one.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss - They run on different hosts, but the host are more or less identical machines, and the VMs are all a copy of the same source VM, with only small application configuration changes.  Being a remote, production machine, replacing the VM is difficult, but is all we can now do.  Still, it would be good to know the cause of the failure.

Comment: Did you run wireshark in VM or host? Try both. Maybe there are different results. Also, do you have 1 or multiple VM per 1 host?

Answer (score 0):

These 3 packets you recorded are the establishing of the connection. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment.
However, if it happens only in 1 VM, then it's no programming issue. Try loading the VMs in different order, check firewall settings etc.
Also, test with a network terminal software like HWGroup Hercules and monitor the connections using Sysinternals TCPView.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected it wasn't the code, and understood that the packets were the connection establishment.  We've done a lot of experimenting on this (including firewall and windows network settings) without any affect.  My question is really asking if anyone can give a reason why this could be occurring.